# How do I reset the last row in Excel when Clear Format is not working?

Tags: excel, formatting

I have a file that has 905,725 active rows, and close to a million blank rows below that. I want the spreadsheet to end at the bottom active row.

I have already tried selecting all the rows below the last active row using CTRL + SHIFT + END, selecting CLEAR > ALL in the edit menu, saving, and closing. When I reopen the spreadsheet, all the rows still appear. I have also cleared all the unused columns to the right of the last active column.

I have tried this with both a CSV and XLSX format with the same results.

I have also tried selecting just the data I want and pasting it in a new sheet, and all the extra rows still show up.

I am using Microsoft Excel for Mac Version 16.16.25. When I type Alt Fn F11, it does not open VBA, just chimes at me, otherwise I would be open to VBA.

Comment: When you open a new, blank worksheet it also has all lines. The numbering can be removed from the *View* menu by unchecking *Headers*. But then you would have to add a column to allocate row numbers in (as far as you want) and probably do the same for columns by adding an extra row 1, noting that your artificial row numbers would then not necessarily coincide with sheet row numbers.

Comment: How can you have a million rows below row 905,725? Excel only supports  1,048,576 in any one sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Excel shows all rows from 1 to 1,048,576 and all columns from A to XFD.

Clearing cells does not remove the rows from the spreadsheet, nor does it hide them.

If you want a sheet to show only the populated cells select the row below the last active row, then use Ctrl+Shift+down arrow to select all rows to the end, then right-click and hide the rows.

Do the same for columns

[image]